# "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager Wont go away

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

I'm on Mac OS 12 and trying to build an IOS app, but for some reason the error:
`Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig" was not found in the UIManager.` doesn't seem to go away needless of what I do.
Here is the Metro Output whenever I reload Metro:[image]

And here is my code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, StyleSheet, StatusBar, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

import fetch from 'node-fetch';

import { NavigationContainer, StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import Main from './pages/main';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const YourApp = () => {

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
        
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name="Main" component={Main} />
            </Stack.Navigator>

        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

export default YourApp;
```

I have been trying to solve this for the past 2 days, thanks for the help!

Comment: did you get any solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

I just faced this issue 3 mins ago. I follow these steps

- Stop metro by `ctrl + c` in terminal
- `npm install @react-navigation/native`
- In project directory run `npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view`
- Install podfile `npx pod-install ios`
- Rebuild your app `npx react-native run-ios`

> This can help ensure that any cached data or previously installed versions of the app are completely removed, which can help resolve issues with missing components or modules.

> This works for me. Hope it can help you!

Comment: It also helps to uninstall the app from the device before rebuilding.

Comment: This can help ensure that any cached data or previously installed versions of the app are completely removed, which can help resolve issues with missing components or modules. @DavidP

Comment: Much clearer explanation than mine, I suggest you add it to the answer, as it's also recommended by the repo owner.

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest version or you can not do cheating on that